# Asp.Net SQL Session Mode won't return JQuery post

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I have a Asp.net Mvc mobile application with jquery coded in front end. It seems that it loses session variables so I changed the session state from in-process to sql server.

I ran:
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319>aspnet_regsql -S NTST-OH-VRS01 -U
dbo -P pass@2014 -ssadd -sstype p

and confirmed that ASPState database exists in the SQL server.

I added sessionState in the web.conifg:

```
<sessionState allowCustomSqlDatabase="true" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider" mode="SQLServer" sqlConnectionString="Server=NTST-OH-VRS01;Database=ASPState;User ID=dbo;Password=pass@2014" timeout="30">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
  </providers>      
</sessionState>
```

and restarted the application pool.

Now when the browser runs $.post(url, ..., function (result){...}), it never comes back from the web server. When I change the session state back to in-process, it's working fine again.

Do you guys know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: did you try clearing browser session and cookies?

Comment: Yes. I tried it, but it still won't return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Process will always work since that means it is using the RAM on the web server.  Using SQL Server can be a bit tricky to setup.  You might be timing out trying to connect to SQL Server.  See if the request returns after 30 seconds.  Also check the following:

- Is the connection string correct?
- Does the SQL user have access to that database?
- Are you using try/catch blocks in your code and logging exceptions?

Comment: The connection string seems to be correct as I see session record in the database and I know I am the only one that is using the SQL server. The database is on the same SQL server that I am getting the data from, so the login should have access to the database as well. I looked at the database and dbo is one of the users that are allowed access to the ASPstate database. I am not using try/catch, but when I put debugger on the returned line and it is never hit and the modal screen I put stays on.

Comment: Also, I used the debugger with Visual Studio 2010 on the server side (Controller object) and it is returning from the post call.

Comment: If the call is returning and you are seeing data in the database, then what is the issue?

Comment: Well, the call to the $.post(url, ..., function (result){...}) is not returning from the server. The web server seems to be replying, but the jQuery post call does not seem to be receiving and it is  waiting from the response...

Comment: Open up the Developer tools in Chrome and see if there is a HTTP error being returned.

Comment: You are right. The post seems to be returning with 500 (internal server error).

Comment: Check out the HTML being returned from your server in the 500 Error. This will give you a clue into what is happening.

Comment: Got it! I looked at the event log and it says that the one of the classes that I was saving to the session variable was not marked as Serializable. I feel so stupid. I never thought it was the problem of code. 

Thank you very much for your help.